# Javascript - How to improve the below regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can this function be improved?

```
function removeLeadingAndTrailingWhitespaceFromString(str) {
    return str.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/ig, "");
}
```

Option a - The g flag can be omitted from the regular expression.
Option b - The * quantifier should be used instead of + to avoid unnecessary replacements.
Option c - There's no need to use capturing parentheses in the regular expression because the values aren't used.
Option d - All of the above

Comment: The function name isn't short at all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is multiple choice

Comment: I feel like I'm reading a test question.

Comment: Well of course there is a correct answer in the given options. But the best answer is provided by Paul S.

Comment: There is no need to use capture groups, however when benchmarked, the margin of error on a time function is greater than any real difference. The answer is `e. None of the above will improve the regex`. Tell your nutty professor to learn regex.

Comment: `iWasAboutToAnswerThisButIGotBoredWhenIstartedReadingTheFunctionName()`

Answer (score 5):

> How can this function be improved?

```
function removeLeadingAndTrailingWhitespaceFromString(str) {
    return str.trim();
}
```

Comment: @sarthaksharma, You wanted to know how to make your function smaller and Paul delivered.